# Surface Plot of a function B(x,y,z)

Tags: matplotlib, plot, multidimensional-array, colors, contour

I have to plot a surface plot which has axes x,y,z and a colormap set by a function of x,y,z [B(x,y,z)].

I have the coordinate arrays:

```
x=np.arange(-100,100,1)
y=np.arange(-100,100,1)
z=np.arange(-100,100,1)
```

Moreover, my to-be-colormap function B(x,y,z) is a 3D array, whose B(x,y,z)[i] elements are the (x,y) coordinates at z.

I have tried something like:

```
Z,X,Y=np.meshgrid(z,x,y) # Z is the first one since B(x,y,z)[i] are the (x,y) coordinates at z.

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


img = ax.scatter(Z, X, Y, c=B(x,y,z), cmap=plt.hot())
fig.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```

However, it unsurprisingly plots dots, which is not what I want. Rather, I need a surface plot.

The figure I have obtained:

[image: My Figure]

The kind of figure I want:

[image: Figure I want]

where the colors are determined by B(x,y,z) for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

- use `plot_surface` to create a surface plot.
- your function `B(x, y, z)` will be used to compute the color parameter, a number assigned to each face of the surface.
- the color parameter must be normalized between 0, 1. We use matplotlib's `Normalize` to achieve that.
- then, you create the colors by applying the colormap to the normalized color parameter.
- finally, you create the plot.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
p = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
t, p = np.meshgrid(t, p)
r1, r2 = 1, 3
x = (r2 + r1 * np.cos(t)) * np.cos(p)
y = (r2 + r1 * np.cos(t)) * np.sin(p)
z = r1 * np.sin(t)
color_param = np.sin(x / 2) * np.cos(y) + z

cmap = cm.jet
norm = Normalize(vmin=color_param.min(), vmax=color_param.max())
norm_color_param = norm(color_param)
colors = cmap(norm_color_param)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, facecolors=colors)
ax.set_zlim(-4, 4)
plt.show()
```